# How to efficiently sample from a datatable by column in R?

Tags: r, data.table, sample

How can I efficiently sample one row for each unique variable in a column from a datatable in R? For example, given the data.table:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

dt <- data.table( 
                   A = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 100, replace = T),
                   B = sample(1:100, 100, replace = T),
                   C = sample(101:200, 100, replace = T) 
                 )
```

I need to sample one row for each unique character in column A. For example:

```
out <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(dt$A))){
  out[[i]] <- dt[sample(dt[, .I[A == unique(dt$A)[i]]], 1, replace = T)]
}
out <- do.call("rbind", out)
```

However, the data table I am applying this to is vary large. Is there a data.table method I can use to improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` on `.N` for each group and select 1 random row.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt[, .SD[sample(.N, 1)], A]

#   A   B   C
#1: A  31 143
#2: D  16 175
#3: B 100 165
#4: E  27 190
#5: C  90 197
```

---

`dplyr` has `slice_sample` (previously `sample_n`) function for it :

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(A) %>% slice_sample(n = 1)
```

Comment: If this is done repeatedly it would make sense to start by `set.key(dt, A)` to improve performance.